# Enforce user id for a field in Firebase Database using rules

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want my users to be able to add `posts` using my app. I need to know who made each post so the client uses

```
this.firebaseapp.database().ref('posts/').push({
        userId, text, timestamp:new Date()
      });
```

Technically though, someone could modify the client and send any value for `userId`, so I need a database rule to prevent this.

The example for user data on the Firebase site mentions:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account
        // whose uid must exactly match the key ($user_id)
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I think I basically want that `.write` restriction but since `Posts` is a different dataset, I don't want to use the Post key, I want to refer to the value that is being passed in.

Here's what I've tried but it allows the posts to be written still:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "posts": {
      "userId": {
        ".write": "newData.val() === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That first code snippet is syntactically incorrect. But let's assume you meant:

```
this.firebaseapp.database().ref('posts/').push({
    userId: userId, text: text, timestamp:new Date()
});
```

The rules you want are:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    "posts": {
      "$postid": {
        ".write": "newData.child('userId').val() === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The key differences:

- I removed the top-level `".write"` rule. Permission cascades down: once you grant access at a certain level, you cannot take it away at a lower level.
- I added back `$postid`, which is needed since this rule needs to apply to all child noders under `/posts`. The `$postid` is really just a wildcard rule to allow that.
- I now ensure you have write permission to the individual post, since doing this on just the `userId` property would not allow the user to write the actual post anymore.

Comment: The first code snippet is ES6, sorry I didn't mention that. New rules work though, thanks!